# array of array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cannot figure out why this is only creating a one dimensional array. What I want is an array of arrays with the inner array being full of items that are strings. Here is my code:

modified_row_id_list is an array of IDs that I have already created. list_of_row is an array of the innerHTML from a row of an HTML table.

```
var modified_rows = new Array(modified_row_id_list.length);
for (i=0; i<modified_row_id_list.length; i++) {
    row = document.getElementById(modified_row_id_list[i]);
    list_of_row = [];

    for (j=0; j<row.cells.length - 1; j++) {
        list_of_row.push(row.cells[j].innerHTML);
        list_of_row.push('-split-')
    }
    modified_rows[i] = [list_of_row];
```

And when  I print out modified_rows it is just a one dimensional array of strings. I know this is probably extremely simple but I can't figure it out for some reason and I'm not all that familiar with javascript.

Comment: "it is just a one dimensional array of strings" - how do you know?

Comment: what happen if you make the last line: `modified_rows[i] = list_of_row;` ?

Comment: `j < row.cells.length;` and `modified_rows[i] = list_of_row;`

Comment: How did you "print out" `modified_rows`? Watch out because `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].toString()` prints `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`, looks can be deceiving.

Comment: Are you modifying `modified_rows` elsewhere? [It works fine here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3qwV8/) (I substituted some values but nothing that affects the accuracy of the function)

Comment: I hand it back to the server by doing: formInfo.elements["modified_row_data"].value = modified_rows; and then in my Python script it is just a 1D list when I print it out. Is there a different way I should pass it? Or can a 2D array not be passed by to Python like that?